# Replace al the <br> tag from a element text Python

Tags: python, selenium

I have a text in a variable:

```
REF: LENOVOSL510A<br><br>Fabricante: Lenovo<br>Modelo: ThinkPad SL510<br>Pantalla: 15.6" HD <br>Procesador: Intel Core2Duo T6670 --  2.2Ghz<br>Memoria: 4Gb<br>Disco Duro: 160Gb SATA<br>Teclado: Castellano.<br>Camara Web: Integrada en el Portátil.<br>
```

Is there is some way that I replace all the `<br>` tag from this text. Note: I get this text from a webelement using Selenium

Comment: I don't see a <br> tag here. using Regex you can do all sorts of manipulations ,look here for 3.6: https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/re.html

Comment: let me explain more clearly, the tag is in the text of the string because I get the text from web table that have this string inside the object

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a simple string replace in python. Here's an example:

```
# DIRTY STRING
dirtyString = 'REF: LENOVOSL510A<br><br>Fabricante: Lenovo<br>Modelo: ThinkPad SL510<br>Pantalla: 15.6" HD <br>Procesador: Intel Core2Duo T6670 --  2.2Ghz<br>Memoria: 4Gb<br>Disco Duro: 160Gb SATA<br>Teclado: Castellano.<br>Camara Web: Integrada en el Portátil.<br>'

# REMOVE
cleanString = dirtyString.replace("<br>", "")

# PRINT
print cleanString
```

If you want to catch all possible line break tags use a regular expression like the following:

```
# IMPORT
import re

# DIRTY STRING
dirtyString = 'REF: LENOVOSL510A<br><br>Fabricante: Lenovo<br>Modelo: ThinkPad SL510<br>Pantalla: 15.6" HD <br>Procesador: Intel Core2Duo T6670 --  2.2Ghz<br>Memoria: 4Gb<br>Disco Duro: 160Gb SATA<br>Teclado: Castellano.<br>Camara Web: Integrada en el Portátil.<br>'

# REMOVE
cleanString = re.sub('<br\s?\/>|<br>', "", dirtyString)

# PRINT
print cleanString
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried this before but for sure I had an error but now it's working

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to replace br, simply do:

```
string.replace("<br>","replacementtext")
```

Example:

```
'REF: LENOVOSL510A<br><br>Fabricante: Lenovo<br>Modelo: ThinkPad 
SL510<br>Pantalla: 15.6" HD <br>Procesador: Intel Core2Duo T6670 --  
2.2Ghz<br>Memoria: 4Gb<br>Disco Duro: 160Gb SATA<br>Teclado: Castellano.
<br>Camara Web: Integrada en el Portátil.<br>'.replace("
<br>","replacementtexthere")
```